# SpringMVC error to run jsp

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a problem with the following code.
When I run mobile/menu it works, but when I run mobile/Home, with a
jsp in WEB-INF/views/Menu.jsp, it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me to find the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile")

public class UsersController {

@Autowired
UsersService userServices;

@RequestMapping(value="/menu", method=RequestMethod.POST,  headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String,Object> getMenu(mng_menu menu){
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            List<mng_menu> list = userServices.listaMenu(); 
            if (list != null){              
                map.put("status","200");
                map.put("message","Data found");
                map.put("data", list);

        }else{
            map.put("status","404");
            map.put("message","Data not found");                
        }       
    return map;
}


 @RequestMapping(value="/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ModelAndView Home(){
        ModelAndView view =new ModelAndView("Menu");
        return view;
    }
```

My SpringMVC-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>


    <servlet>   
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mobile/Home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mobile/menu</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list> 

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What error did u get?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: 'headers="Accept=application/json")' Is this the correct return?

Comment: Did you read successfully from userServices.listaMenu() ?

Comment: userServices.listaMenu() run. the headers is correct